# Stop access to files in a directory on the browser with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web

I have a directory like so:

```
appname
    |
    |public/
    |   |
    |   |foobar.php
    |
    |barfoo/
```

If a user opens their browser to see the app they can see the folder structure and it's files if they get to https://host/appname. I have the Directory Index to look at foobar.php so when the user goes to https://host/appname/public. Foobar get's rendered fine. But I can still access the files with https://host/appname.

Should I have another .htaccess fill in the same directory as public and boofar like I do in public?

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm trying to learn.

Comment: Configure your web server so that this app is on a vhost by itself and then set the document_root setting  to be `appname/public`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in a .htaccess file this (put it in the `appname` folder):

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Would that be in the same level as public and barfoo? Are you allowed to have multiple htaccess files? Just trying to get best standards :)

Comment: @SmiffyKmc Just put in the same existent .htaccess

Comment: I added that in the existent .htaccess file which is inside public but that still shows the contents of appname. Should the htaccess file not be in public but be in appname? Thanks!

Comment: Put an .htaccess file with that line in the level above (appname). By the way, you can have also multiple .htaccess files.

Comment: This doesn't prevent Apache from serving the non-public files, it only prevents the directory listing of them. You'll still be able to hit `http://host/appname/barfoo/some_file`.

Comment: Done that and it worked! I tried looking around but nothing made sense as to where you should put it, how many you should have for best practice etc. But ye all have really helped! Thank you!